# Downloading public files in Google Drive (Python)

Tags: python

Suppose that someone gives me a link that enables me to download a public file in Google Drive.

I want to write a program that can read the link and then download it as a text file.

For example, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yJVXtabsP7KrJXSu3XyOh-F2cFoP8Lftr14PtXCLEVU/edit is one of files in my Google Drive.
Everyone can access this file.

But how can I write a Python program that downloads the text file given the above link?

Could someone have some pieces of sample code for me?

It seems that some Google Drive SDK could be useful(?), but is there any way to do it without using SDK?

Comment: Check out `urllib2` (or `urllib` in Py3).

Comment: @larsmans Because the link will direct me to an edit page, I cannot download the file directly although I know urllib2. To download the file, I need to manually click the menu and select "save file." Can you be more specific how I can use urllib2?

Comment: get up the chrome developer tools (ctrl,shift,i) and when you download the file look at what URL is present in the network part. Then take that URL and use that to get the document in the relevant format. Doing that on your link I can see a "export?format=" is added. However so is a "token" that probably prevents this working at all.

Comment: @PaulC Sorry I didn't get what you said. I clicked the link and went to the edit page. Then, I got up the chrome developer tool, within which I searched for "export?format=" but cannot find anyone.

Comment: do the export, then on the new url that appears in the network section you can get a direct url to the .txt file. perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

first you need to write a  program that would slice off the link of the file that you have uploaded.
for example in the link that you gave:
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yJVXtabsP7KrJXSu3XyOh-F2cFoP8Lftr14PtXCLEVU/edit

id is ***1yJVXtabsP7KrJXSu3XyOh-F2cFoP8Lftr14PtXCLEVU***

save it in some variable , say download_link
now to get the download link:
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=download_link
this link will download the file

Answer (score 1):

If the above answer doesn't work for you use the following links :

to save as .txt file :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yJVXtabsP7KrJXSu3XyOh-F2cFoP8Lftr14PtXCLEVU/export?format=txt

to save as docx file:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yJVXtabsP7KrJXSu3XyOh-F2cFoP8Lftr14PtXCLEVU/export?format=docx

generally the trick is to add : export?format=txt instead of edit ! hope it helps.