# Download Google Drive file via python 3

Tags: python

I only have access to a jupyter notebook on a server and I need to download and unzip a large file on Google Drive. Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bz1dfcnrpXM-MUt4cHNzUEFXcmc&export=download). I am using python 3. This is a large dataset of images that is 37GB unzipped. I wasn't able to get Urllib to work, I am guessing it has to do with it being https but I have no idea.

What link should I use? Should I use the link to the page or the link on the button on that page?

I do not want it as text so it is unlike this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529177/downloading-public-files-in-google-drive-python).

Comment: Downloading a text file should work no differently than downloading a several gigabyte zip file. Whether you treat the contents of the file as text or not *after you've downloaded it* should not affect how you download it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The other question does not go into how to download the file in addition to turning the file into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the Google Drive API for that.

Google Drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Here is an example provided on the website to download a file from the drive:

```
file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

Comment: Returns a 0 when I do this. How do I know that I am downloading the file?

Comment: I was wrong on my post, you can't wget files from Google Drive since it's not authenticated, I will edit my answer.